# What are the conditions for a second order nonhomogenous ODE with $q(x) = A_1\sin(Bx)+A_2\cos(Bx)$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In my notes it states that it

$y_1$ $\neq$ $\mathbf e$sin(Bx)

as one of the conditions and this is the one I am confused about. There is no $\mathbf e$ in the original equation so is this a typo in my lecture?

Comment: Can you set notation?

Comment: @ncmathsadist What does that mean, sorry?

Comment: What is $q(x)$ and what is $\mathbf{e}$?  Is the DE linear?

Comment: @ncmathsadist So I have a second order differential which is equal to q(x). The conditions are that none of the AiAi = 0 and that the first solution to the second order differential Y1Y1 is not = to eSin(Bx). And also that the second solution Y2Y2 is not = to Cos(Bx). The last one makes sense and so does the first but the one = eSin(Bx) is the one I don't understand since there was no e in the original second order differential

Comment: @ncmathsadist sorry that got a little messy if you need more clarification I'll write the entire thing out.

Comment: Is it possible that it was $y_1\ne e^x\sin(Bx)$? Depending upon the particular second order equation $e^x\sin(Bx)$ could make sense.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales The second order equation is of the form $Y^{''}$+a$Y^{'}$+bY = q(x) where q(x) is of the form in the original question. Do you see why i'm confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will interpret the question as follows:

Given that $y=c_1y_1+c_2y_2+y_p$ is a solution of

\begin{equation}
y^{\prime\prime}+ay^\prime+by=A_1\sin(Bx)+A_2\cos(Bx)
\end{equation}

and that there is no solution containing a term of the form $e^{\alpha x}\cos(Bx)$, find a general solution.

Since if $a^2<4b$ the general solution of the corresponding homogeneous equation

\begin{equation}
y_c^{\prime\prime}+ay_c^\prime+by_c=0
\end{equation}

will be

\begin{equation}
y_c=e^{-\frac{a}{2}x}\left[ c_1\sin\left(\frac{\sqrt{4b-a^2}}{2}x\right)+c_2\cos\left(\frac{\sqrt{4b-a^2}}{2}x\right)\right]
\end{equation}

the condition would suggest that either

$a^2>4b$ or

$a^2=4b$

Therefore the general form of the particular solution should be

\begin{equation}
y_p=\gamma_1\sin(Bx)+\gamma_2\cos(Bx)
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks for this. That is what I have gotten under the instructions I have but they list a bunch of conditions that must be met first. They include that; $A_1$ $\neq$ 0 and same for $A_2$. Aswell as, $Y_2$ $\neq$ cos(Bx) and finally $Y_1$ $\neq$ eSin(Bx). The last condiiton is the one I don't understand since it has an e involved. I think it is a mistake but I need confirmation from somebody who has met these conditions before?

Comment: If there is no $e$ in the other conditions then it could be a mistake.